# How can I verify that my security is up to paypal standards?

Tags: paypal, sha256, root-certificate

Tomorrow paypal will be flipping the switch for two hours on mandatory sha-256 and g5 root certificates. Here's the link:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en

We use payflow pro which is at the bottom of the third table. How can I verify that we are up to date before the two hour test occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The 2 hour period will basically test it for you

There are several resources linked in the document you reference, most notably [this](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/resources/sites/PAYPAL/content/live/FAQ/1000/FAQ1766/en_US/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20%28U.S.%20English%29.pdf%20/%22this%22). However, you need to be sure you have 1. Discontinued use of the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate, and 2. Updated your integration to support certificates using the SHA-256 algorithm.

The document I linked should guide you down the correct path.